# play audio effect in Unity without joining a channel?

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio, agora.io

I want to play an audio effect and was using Unity's built in audio player. However after I connected to a channel, it would break. So I switched to using Agora to play the audio files. Now, I can't play an audio file unless I am joined to a room. How do I go about playing an audio file before I join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this call when using Unity build in audio player:

mRtcEngine.SetParameters("{"che.audio.keep.audiosession": true}");

Comment: we are now noticing we are having horrible echo after we have set this... how do we have AEC settings enabled and able to play Unity audio?

Comment: Hi Greg, for AEC issues please check this FAQ: https://docs.agora.io/en/faq/echo